# Redux - Angular2/ngrx handling state in child components

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

there is rule in redux that state should be modified only in reducers. Does anyone knows best practices for handling state into child components? i mean how to react on some event in component which is not "container" should child component be able to modify its internal @intput model or it should only trigger some event which then "container" should transform into action dispatch and model change should return back to this component via @input? or child component can modify its model ? let say we have datepicker component. When selecting date in handler functions should we update this.date or we should only trigger dateChange event and wait for model to being changed by container? thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is good concept of stateful and stateless components in Angular ecosystem. So it depend what challenges you are trying to achieve:

- does your component can receive initial data from your route
- does components has living knowledge of the current state
- is this information valid between other components state changes
- how many external dependencies/communications this component has
- has stateful/stateless child components, etc
- contains Redux actions (ngrx/store or ng2redux for example)

Please read this article to get more information about differences between this component types.

After that you need to draw your own picture what kind of approach is best suited to your own architecture.

https://toddmotto.com/stateful-stateless-components

Answer (score -1):

so my example looks like below:

```
<plumb [nodes]='nodes$|async' [connections]='connections$|async'  (connect)='onConnect($event)' (disconnect)='onDisconnect($event)')/>
```

basicaly its graph control to draw diagrams.. i am givint this cmoponent as parameters list of blocks/ndoes and list of connection and i am triggering two events when user connects items or disconets in graph.. so the question is if modification of "connections" list should be inside component or when user draw connection component should trigger event and wait with drawing arrow till ngrx store will handle it and give back new list of connections:) i dont wanna this componnet to be awawre of store cause i want this to be reusable.. according to article you sent looks like its better to have components stateles so it shouldnt modify connections list itselfe. thanks

Comment: I think in your case you need both - stateful components to encapsulate component specific behaviors and related data for better unit-testing in future and better regression protection and fire events outside to manage components communications. Does this make sense in your case?

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking also .. i dont wanna to mutate collection of "connections" passed to component beacues its redux no no.. so i was thinking about making a copy inside this component and operate on this list and inform outside world that source connections list needst be changed.. howeve havent seen such pattern in any code so far:)